# Qt 3D Failed to build graphics pipeline

Tags: qt, qt3d

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Qt6.4.2. When I try to run Qt3D example [Basics Shapes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html) it shows the error:

```
Qt3D.Renderer.RHI.Backend: Initializing RHI with OpenGL backend
No GLSL shader code found (versions tried:  QList(130, 120) ) in baked shader QShader(stage=0 shaders=QList(ShaderKey(1 Version(300 QFlags()) 0)) desc.isValid=true)
No GLSL shader code found (versions tried:  QList(130, 120) ) in baked shader QShader(stage=4 shaders=QList(ShaderKey(1 Version(300 QFlags()) 0)) desc.isValid=true)
No GLSL shader code found (versions tried:  QList(130, 120) ) in baked shader QShader(stage=0 shaders=QList(ShaderKey(1 Version(300 QFlags()) 0)) desc.isValid=true)
Qt3D.Renderer.RHI.Backend: Failed to build graphics pipeline: Creation Failed
```

What does it mean?

UPDATED:

Output of "glxinfo -B | less":

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) (0x166)
    Version: 21.2.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.2
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: go and look into qt source code (you have some strings to search for).

Comment: What are your graphic card and OpenGL versions? Do you have a graphic card? please check `glxinfo -B | less`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I added output of this command to my message.

Comment: I guess they changed one of the core 3d class in qt 6.4.0 and it requires a graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I test that Example in `Qt 6.4.0` and `Qt 6.2.3`.
and for this test, I use NVIDIA GPU and my Intel.

**This is my Intel config**

[image]

**and as I run that Example in `Qt 6.4.0` I got the same error you got.**

[image]

[image]

**But As I change my GPU to NVIDIA, it works correctly!**

**I test that program with `Qt 6.2.3` and Intel GPU and it runs and works correctly!**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. I added DRI_PRIME=1 to /etc/environment. And it helps me to switch GPU to AMD.